# how to configure PyDev to debug external app that runs embedded python scripts?

Tags: python, debugging, aptana

I'm not sure if this question has been answered yet, but I couldn't find any answers.

I'm making a stand alone app in C++ that needs to execute python code. So, I'm embedding python and running it ok.

My questions is, how can I use PyDev to debug the python code executed by this stand alone app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are referreing to [Pydev Remote Debugger](http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html). It allow you to create a server in the 'debugee' process, using:

```
import pydevd; pydevd.settrace()
```

and then connect to it from pydev.

Also, [Winpdb](http://winpdb.org/) has similar functionality.